# setting locale in blueprintjs datetime react component

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, blueprintjs

I'm trying to set the locale of blueprintjs `DateRangeInput`. The docs state that the Component uses Moment.js for localisation. So I tried to set `locale="de"`, but the language is English still. Any ideas what is missing to get a translated date input?

I'm fairly new to React programming so I can't be sure that it has nothing to do with my React skills, even tho passing the props seems quite right to me.

```
<DateRangeInput
    locale={"de"}
    value={dates}
    onChange={...}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this `import "moment/locale/de"` to the top of the file

i think blueprint uses `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)` to remove the locales from moment which is pretty common since moment is really large.

if that doesn't work  try adding this to your webpack plugins

`new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /de/)`

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I added the `import` to my component's file and also the snippet for webpack's plugins section, but still the date picker is all english. The import is not throwing any errors so I guess the moment locale was loaded correctly. I don't see, why it is still not working :( I'll have a look if I can update any libraries.

Comment: it seems like `DateRangeInput` uses `react-day-picker` http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/localization/, they suggest also passing the `localeUtils` props

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime components (Date picker, Date range picker, Time picker, Date time picker, Date input, and Date range input) all depend on react-day-picker.

To set the desired locale, according to the [react-day-picker documentation](https://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/localization/) you need to import the desired locale from moment as mentioned above and set the localeUtils (a set of functions used to render the component based on the current locale).

The code below is how it works.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { DateRangeInput } from "@blueprintjs/datetime";
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';

// Include the locale utils designed for moment
import MomentLocaleUtils from 'react-day-picker/moment';

// Make sure moment.js has the required locale data
import 'moment/locale/ja';

export default class LocalizedExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DateRangeInput localeUtils={MomentLocaleUtils} locale='ja' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```